# MTU mismatch between netsh and NetworkInterface.GetIPProperties()

Tags: c#, networking, mtu

Related to [How to get the current MTU of an interface in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666933/463115)
But that solution (set both mtu sizes to the same value), doesn't help in my case.

There exists a problem in `GetIPv4Properties()`, if the mtu sizes for ipv4 and ipv6 are set differently, then...

If ipv6 is enabled, both (GetIPv4Properties/GetIPv6Properties) return the mtu size of ipv6!
The Mtu value is only correct if the ipv6 protocol is disabled.

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    if (ni.Name == "Local Area Connection")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ni.GetIPProperties().GetIPv4Properties().Mtu);
        Console.WriteLine(ni.GetIPProperties().GetIPv6Properties().Mtu);
    }
}
```

But the correct values are shown by netsh

```
netsh interface ipv4 show subinterface "Local Area Connection"
netsh interface ipv6 show subinterface "Local Area Connection"
```

Without protocol version, the value for ipv4 is shown.

```
netsh interface ip show subinterface "Local Area Connection"
```

In my case, I need to check the mtu size for ipv4 independent of the ipv6 protocol enabled or disabled state.
Because my SW only works, if the mtu size is set to 1500 and I want to warn the user otherwise.

Is it possible with the NetworkInterface class or should I use a nasty hack, like

```
Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("netsh.exe", "interface ipv4 show subinterface \"Local Area Connection\"") {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            });
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

**@EDIT:**
After the comments from @RonMaupin

> There is no difference in MTU for IPv4 or IPv6, which are layer-3
>   protocols. The MTU is the maximum payload size of the layer-2
>   protocol, e.g. ethernet

That is correct, but for windows each protocol uses it's own mtu size and fragmentation.
Tested with mtu ipv4=1300 vs ipv6=1500 and ping of 1400 bytes:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Local Area Connection" mtu=1300 store=persistent
netsh interface ipv6 set subinterface "Local Area Connection" mtu=1500 store=persistent

ping6 -c 5 ff02::1:3 -s 1400
```

> 112   28.860467   fe80::64aa:56e9:fb1e:2081   ff02::1:3   ICMPv6  1462    Echo
>   (ping) request id=0x3160, seq=2, hop limit=1 (multicast)

```
ping 192.168.101.11 -s 1400
```

> 152   102.027390  192.168.101.223 192.168.101.11  IPv4    1314    Fragmented IP
>   protocol (proto=ICMP 1, off=0, ID=2712)
>   153   102.027409  192.168.101.223 192.168.101.11  ICMP    162 Echo (ping)
>   request  id=0x3450, seq=0/0, ttl=128 (no response found!)

Comment: There is no difference in MTU for IPv4 or IPv6, which are layer-3 protocols. The MTU is the maximum payload size of the layer-2 protocol, e.g. ethernet.

Comment: @RonMaupin, no quite correct in the case of windows. My profinet stack only works reliable when the MTU size of ipv4=1500, but not when ipv4=1300, ipv6=1500

Comment: The MTU is a layer-2 value (the payload size of the layer-2 frame), and it has nothing to do with the layer-3 protocol used. The layer-3 packet is the payload of the layer-2 frame, and layer-2 does not know or care what layer-3 protocol is carried in the frame. The layer-2 payload size is the layer-2 payload size, regardless of the layer-3 protocol. The layer-3 protocol could even be IPX or AppleTalk, and the layer-2 payload size (MTU) would remain the same because the layer-2 protocol is ignorant of the layer-3 protocol.